# Error $injector, ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

Hi guys I've got this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">          
        <div class="main">
            {{hello world}}
            <div ng-view></div>

        </div>

    </div>



<script>
    var app=angular.module('app',[]);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routerProvider.
        when('/',{templateUrl: 'partials/directory.html'})
        .when('/view/:id',{templateUrl:'partials/view.html',
                controller:viewController})
        .otherwise({redirecTo:'/'})
    });

    app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        $http.jsonp('http://www.filltext.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}&tel={phone}').success(function(data){
            $scope.people=data;
        });
    }]);

    app.controller('viewController',['$scope','$routeParams',function($scope,$routeParams){
            $scope.person=$scope.people[$routeParams.id];
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I'm trying to run it there is $injector error i guess it's because of `controller` injection.
I hope i don't have another typo but i did check it for that.
Can you help me out please:)

Answer (score 0):

you need to load ngRoute as a module dependency.
Check here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

```
var app=angular.module('app',[
  'ngRoute'
]);
```

Comment: there is still another problem besides this

Comment: Ok, Mark Harry is right you also need to load thi library: check here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Answer (score 0):

In the html you need to correct the script tag for angular-route.js to be:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Also in the javascript you need to inject the ngRoute service to the app and correct the routes as you need to change the controller to be a string and there is a spelling mistake on the `.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});`

```
var app=angular.module('app',["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routerProvider.
    when('/',{templateUrl: 'partials/directory.html'})
    .when('/view/:id',{templateUrl:'partials/view.html',
            controller:'viewController'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Noupe it didn't help ... i have still same error what concerns me is that simple expression isn't loaded right i still getting  result as {{hello world}} that's why i think it controller broblem

Comment: @Artur, that's because you have many more bugs: you have `$routerProvider` (not `$routeProvider`), you have `{{hello world}}` when you probably meant `Hello {{world}}`. For future reference, remove the .min from the angular script for easier debugging

Comment: thank you i fix even conroller 'viewConroller' was without quotes but now im getting multiple errors

Comment: You will still be getting an error in with the `{{hello world}}` binding because its in a view controlled by a controller its looking for a `$scope` value that matches that. if you changed it to `{{ helloWorld }}` then in your `myCtrl` controller have something like `$scope.helloWorld = "Hello World";` then it should work.

Comment: You are right if i write {{'hello world'}} it works but now i got Failed to load directory.html and Unexpected token >